# SVN compare with latest in repository issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using SVN. When I did- "compare file with latest version in repository" , it showed no difference. Then I accidently did "replace file with latest from repository". I suddenly realized that there were lot of changes...

Can somebody explain what might have happened??.

thanks in advance

Comment: `svn` is a command line tool and I don't think it has such command. Are you talking about TortoiseSVN?

Comment: I suppose those are not actual menu items but vague descriptions of the steps you followed. Do you mean "Diff with previous version" and "Update to revision"? If so, did you update to *previous* revision? Are you talking about a file with uncommitted changes?